# Load .properties file from IDE and also from outside of JAR

Tags: java, maven, properties, jar

I have a `app.properties` file in my maven project under `resources` folder as shown here (simplified):

```
myApp
  |----src
  |     |
  |     |--main
  |         |--java
  |         |    |--ApplicationInitializer.java
  |         |
  |         |--resources
  |              |--app.properties
  |
  |---target
        |--myApp.jar
        |--app.properties
```

In `ApplicationInitializer` class I want to load properties from the `app.properties` file with following piece of code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

String path = "/app.properties";

try {
    props.load(ApplicationInitializer.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(props.getProperty("property"));
```

This piece of code loads properties correctly when I run it from inside my IDE but fails with exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at cz.muni.fi.fits.ApplicationInitializer.main(ApplicationInitializer.java:18)
```

when trying to run in as JAR file.

For creating a jar file I am using combination of **`maven-shade-plugin`**, **`maven-jar-plugin`** (for excluding properties file outside of the JAR) and **`maven-resources-plugin`** (for copying properties file to specific folder) in `pom.xml` file as shown here:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>cz.muni.fi.fits.ApplicationInitializer</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resource</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I then switched the code in main method to this one:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

String path = "./app.properties";

try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(path)) {
    props.load(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(props.getProperty("property"));
```

and managed to load properties from file when running JAR but this time I was not able to load them when running in IDE, it ended with the same exception as above.

So my question is: **How to set the filepath (or `pom.xml` file?) that I will be able to load properties running from both IDE and JAR file?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I see in `target` you have `myApp.jar` and `app.properties`. Can you check if `app.properties` is inside `.jar` file?

Comment: No it is not, that's why I am using `maven-jar-plugin` to exclude it from jar

Comment: Why are you trying to put the property file outside the jar file? If you do so you can't use `getResourcesAsStream()`.

Comment: I want to put it outside because I want the user to be able to edit configuration of app simply with edit of properties file (no input parameters or so).

Answer (score 0):

The way you're working at the moment you depend on the working directory of your java process. Typically that's the your command line (aka shell) points to, when starting the application.

On most IDE's you can configure this directory in your launcher settings. (For eclipse it's on the second tab 'Arguments') So you will need to the target directory (For eclipse there's a button 'Workspace...')

Specifically in intelliJ you can find this setting under Run/Edit Configurations... This will open a window like this:
[image]
There you can edit the working directory. You simply add target at the end.

Edit:
Actually you've add src/main/ressources at the end.

Comment: So what is your suggestion? I am sorry but I don't understand your answer.

Comment: My suggestíon is to configure your IDE to launch the java process with right working directory. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14

Comment: This is not solving the problem with loading file becuase `app.properties` gets copied to `target` directory only when I package the app with maven. So with this I wouldn't need `resources` folder, I would treat that properties file as ordinary file.

Comment: Yes, if it's not included to the jar it's an ordinary file. But if the question is: How can I find a file no matter where it lays, the answer is 'You can't. If the question is: I've two usecases. How can I deal with?' then I gave the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to clarify if there is not some other way how it can work both from IDE and JAR with two properties files (or with one which gets copied after package phase).

Answer (score 0):

In your Java code read your `app.properties` file like this:

```
final String ROOT_PATH = "custom.path"; // Or whatever you most like
final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "app.properties";

// start :: try-catch here to manage I/O resources
File directory = new File(System.getProperty(ROOT_PATH), "conf");
File file = new File(directory, PROPERTIES_FILE);
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
// ...
// end :: try-catch here to manage I/O resources
```

Then you have to ways for setting/declaring `custom.path`:

- Declaring it as an environment variable
- Setting it at *run-time* (environment properties) with the `-Dcustom.path=/somewhere/in/your/filesystem` (I prefer this one, unless the path is fixed and/or shared across different applications)

Then, eventually you need to copy/put your `app.properties` file inside `/somewhere/in/your/filesystem/conf`. And why inside `/conf`? Because you use it when you declare the `directory` field. If you don't want it in there just don't set it and delete the `, "conf"` part.

Additionally, for running it "locally" (in your IDE) use the **VM options** setting (IntelliJ IDEA):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising but it's a bit overkill for me to define the path as environment variable and also I cannot use the runtime argument because it would mess with my current arguments.

Comment: @Supermartzin I can understand the "environment variable" part, but runtime arguments (environment properties) you can have as many as you want, and they won't interfere between each other

Comment: Sure, you're right but it would debase a lucidity of my program and I want to aviod that. Thanks anyway for the advice.